# Pong via Python Turtle issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

I've been looking at this for hours and can't figure out why it won't run properly. Any ideas? I've tried messing with different x and y coords to see if that was the problem but nothing works.
The program just runs twitches and ends, when it should be playing through a game of pong until the user exits out.

code: you can ignore the comments

```
import turtle

# screen
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.title('Pong')
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.setup(width=1000, height=500)

# ball
ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.shape('circle')
ball.color('white')
ball.speed(0)
ball.penup()                                        #solves line issue
ball.goto(0, 0)
ball.dx = 5
ball.dy = -5

# right paddle____add speed___
r_pad = turtle.Turtle()
r_pad.speed(0.5)
r_pad.shape('square')
r_pad.color('white')
r_pad.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=2)
r_pad.penup()
r_pad.goto(450, 0)

# left paddle
l_pad = turtle.Turtle()
l_pad.speed(0.5)
l_pad.shape('square')
l_pad.color('white')
l_pad.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=2)
l_pad.penup()
l_pad.goto(-450, 0)


# Score
score = turtle.Turtle()
score.speed(0)
score.color('white')
score.penup()
score.hideturtle()
score.goto(0, 200)
score.write("Left_player : 0 Right_player: 0",
             align="center", font=("arial", 24, "normal"))
#solving that score error
left_player = 0
right_player = 0

# movement
def paddler_up():
    y = r_pad.ycor()
    y += 20
    r_pad.sety(y)


def paddler_down():
    y = r_pad.ycor()
    y -= 20
    r_pad.sety(y)


def paddlel_up():
    y = l_pad.ycor()
    y += 20
    l_pad.sety(y)


def paddlel_down():
    y = l_pad.ycor()
    y -= 20
    l_pad.sety(y)



#main game
screen.listen()
screen.onkeypress(paddler_up, "w")
screen.onkeypress(paddler_down, "s")
screen.onkeypress(paddlel_up, "up")
screen.onkeypress(paddlel_down, "down")



while True:
    screen.update()

    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

    # Checking borders
    if ball.ycor() > 230:
        ball.sety(230)
        ball.dy *= -1

    if ball.ycor() < -230:
        ball.sety(-230)
        ball.dy *= -1

    if ball.xcor() > 600:
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dy *= -1
        left_player += 1
        score.clear()
        score.write("Left_player : {} Right_player: {}".format(
            left_player, right_player), align="center",
            font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))

    if ball.xcor() < -600:
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dy *= -1
        right_player += 1
        score.clear()
        score.write("Left_player : {} Right_player: {}".format(
            left_player, right_player), align="center",
            font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))

    # Paddle ball collision
    if (ball.xcor() > 360 and ball.xcor() < 370) \
            and (ball.ycor() < r_pad.ycor() + 40 and ball.ycor() > r_pad.ycor() - 40):
        ball.setx(360)
        ball.dx *= -1

    if (ball.xcor() < -360 and ball.xcor() > -370) \
            and (ball.ycor() < l_pad.ycor() + 40 and ball.ycor() > l_pad.ycor() - 40):
        ball.setx(-360)
        ball.dx *= -1
```

Comment: *"it won't run properly"* is a very unclear description, dare to elaborate?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `onkeypress` calls for up and down keys should be capitalized (`Up` and `Down` instead of `up` and `down`) for it to work

```
screen.onkeypress(paddlel_up, "Up")
screen.onkeypress(paddlel_down, "Down")
```

Comment: The capitalization fixed it. Thanks.